# J Meter not reaching on the desired page

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3353.png)In Jmeter, after login when i clicked on any of the page script records but when i run the scripts and see the result in "View Result Tree" listner, it seems, my request did not reach on the next page after login.

it always shows, username and password field in the HTML view.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Does the website use cookies?

Comment: No, I guess. How to check this?

Comment: can you show your Test plan? Does it include `HTTP Cookie Manager`?

Comment: Always record using Recording Template from JMeter : https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html    Can you check and let us know?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your POST request is failing due to missing or improperly working [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

My expectation is that you need to execute a [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request first to load the login page, extract [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and other dynamic parameters (if any) and add them to the POST request which does the login.

Simplified Test Plan Structure:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- HTTP Request Sampler - GET the login page

  - [PostProcessor(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract dynamic parameters
- HTTP Request Sampler - POST (provide credentials and parameters from the previous response)
- HTTP Request Sampler - Sale Page

More information: [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations/)